# Git log: filter by commit's author date

Tags: git

I have such a commit

```
commit 8a183536da1641afa6bd5a27ae391b387b7cd052
Author:     hidden
AuthorDate: Fri Sep 7 10:13:59 2012
Commit:     hidden
CommitDate: Fri Dec 7 17:29:24 2012
```

I want to filter the log and show the commit by **AuthorDate**.

I tried `--since` & `--until` options, but it actually filter  the **CommitDate**.

That means I can only get the commit by

```
git log --since='2012-12-01' --until='2012-12-10'
```

If I want to get the commit filter by  start_date '2012-09-01' and end_date '2012-09-10'

Any tips?

Comment: @skalee `Sep` and `Dec` are not the same thing...

Comment: See: [How to get git to show commits in a specified date range for author date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311494/how-to-get-git-to-show-commits-in-a-specified-date-range-for-author-date)

Answer (score 15):

```
git log --format=format:"%ai %aE %s"
```

and then grep by AuthorName and/or date!

Comment: like this: `git log --format=format:"%ai %aE %s" | grep '^2020-05-29.*user@email.*$'`

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid you need to do some scripting:

```
git log --format="%ad %H" --date=iso | sort | ruby -ane 'date = $F[0] ; hash = $F[3] ; puts hash if ("2013-08-23".."2013-09-26").cover?(date)'
```

gave to me:

```
3eddb854eaea971e9a60147153f0f3c9be4f1a5a
dfeefd4715c4fddef0957c5aff238c525bb1def6
db654badb97f3784286171d4645e9face6a42865
62cdba07e6ae0cd28752491a83f584d3e18a5619
7643a0458a54200f8944583d66c089d63c1bf688
23b720852a36e959d0f45f9d11f05d4aa7ee0cb9
f729ec9c5bf37ee0284a8db47cbc79a0b53145bb
bc2d647ae86fbff1246ba163a5a99d25ed2f3523
a0752b3cbae39698449be953153ddaafe35c054c
8e88fffc75cbdda333c86cb4f5eb9b5b30263c27
```

Unfortunately, `git log 3eddb854eaea971e9a60147153f0f3c9be4f1a5a..8e88fffc75cbdda333c86cb4f5eb9b5b30263c27` is not guaranteed to work because those commits may be in different branches.

Let's explain what I did:

1. `--format="%ad %H"` – format log as `author_date commit_hash` lines
2. `--date=iso` – dates in `YY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format
3. `sort` – Unix command which sorts lines alphabetically; it's suitable to sort dates in ISO format
4. `ruby -ane` – execute ruby script. -n means execute for every line, -a split those lines and put fields into `$F` array, -e precises script to execute
5. `("2011-02-23".."2011-02-26").cover?(date)` – create range from two strings and check if date fits it inclusively (in the meaning of alphabetical order, we were not parsing those dates)

I have no idea what to do next (to give you nicer log), but glad to move you to this point.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes want to find the commits authored by me on a certain date. For that I use `git log --all --author=jpo --format="%ai %s" |grep -E ^2015-09-01`. Unfortunately that approach wont work for filtering by date range in general but for the range used in the question it could be easily done: `git log --all --author=jpo --format="%ai %s" |grep -E ^2012-12-(0.|10)` If you want more information about the commits besides author date and commit message just add more parameters to the format string (check the PRETTY FORMATS section of the `git help log` page).

Comment: This is a really powerful method. I've been using it with a slight tweak to review months or quarters worth of work to look back on "what did I do this quarter?" `git log --all --author=cabbey --format="%as %h %s %d" | grep -E ^2021-1[012]-` for example. `%h` comes in handy to be able to copy/paste the hash onto a `git show` command, and `%d` adds the branch names (I'm horrible about cleaning them up, but that comes in handy here) for final commits on each branch which helps me know when I stopped working on that topic.