# Git log before some commit date

Tags: git

I'm trying to get all commits before some date from AOSP (android open source project).
I found that I can do it by git command:
`git log --before="2011-12-01"`

But it shows me only `author date` (date when patch or change was uploaded buy not merged/changed)

Also I found that I  can get date which I need by next `git`  command:
`git log --pretty=format:"%cd"`
I't will show `commit date`.

And the question is:
how can get git log before some `commit date`?

Comment: Have your read the [man page for git log](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) and then tried `--pretty=short`?

Comment: @RedX yes but I don't see difference between 
git log --before="2011-12-01" --pretty=format:"%ad"
git log --before="2011-12-01" --pretty=format:"%cd"

Comment: What about: `git log --before="2011-12-01" --pretty=short`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simply combine the two:

```
git log --before="2011-12-01" --pretty=format:"%cd"
```

As shown in "[Git log: filter by commit's author date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13987273/6309)", [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) filters by commit date, and the `pretty=format` will display just that.

From the man page:

> Using more options generally further limits the output (e.g. `--since=<date1>` limits to commits newer than `<date1>`)

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't see difference between 
@RedX yes but I don't see difference between 
`git log --before="2011-12-01" --pretty=format:"%ad"`
`git log --before="2011-12-01" --pretty=format:"%cd"` and
`git log --before="2011-12-01"`
but I hope it should be there.

Comment: @Pepelac probably because the commit and author date are the same (or very close)

Comment: I hope on it but no 
see an example here http://pastebin.com/33pU7Ejp
%ad does not affect on `git log`

Comment: Interestingly enough, `--before` works like something that would be called `--before-or-on`.