# Does any know why `before` include finish date?

Tags: git, git-log

Does any know why `before` include finish date?

The date `2021-07-01 14:13` actually is after `2021-07-01`

[image]

Why results are wrong?

git version is 2.32.0

Comment: Given that `--before` and `--until` are synonyms, and it makes sense for `--until` to be inclusive, I lean towards "poorly documented" rather than "buggy". (One could also charitably argue that `2021-07-21` is short for `021-07-21 23:59:59`.)

Comment: Perhaps the documentation could use some updating. Other's have [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110178/git-log-before-some-commit-date#comment114867287_19110603) on this as well.

Comment: Programmers are notoriously bad for understanding or adhering to normal concepts and expectations, so programmers shouldn't be the ones making user interfaces. This includes command-line commands, options and arguments. Only a programmer can develop a believable explanation for why "before a certain date" also includes that date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note the date filters use the commit datetime, not the author datetime.

Although it isn't documented, as noted in [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68232215/184546) and confirmed by my limited testing, surprisingly, it appears that all the date filters, when a time is not specified, refer to the current time of the day on your client machine! Note you can specify a time if you wish to override that:

`git log --before=2021-07-02T23:59:59` (end of the day)

or

`git log --before=2021-07-02T00:00:00` (beginning of the day)

Below is my test script. It generates a new repo with one empty commit with a committer date from 2 days ago minus 1 minute. (So that 1 minute from now the commit will be exactly 2 days ago.) Then the script loops for a minute and every 10 seconds it prints out the current time, as well as the log using `--before` and `--after` options. At first --before doesn't show anything and --after shows the commit, but after a minute the logs flip once the current time surpasses that of the commit date:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create a test repo
git init
echo ""

# create a date which is 2 days ago minus 1 minute
var1=$(date --date '-2879 min')
# create a date that is the first date in only YYYY-MM-DD format
var2=$(date -d "$var1" +%F)
# show the variables
echo "var1=$var1"
echo "var2=$var2"
echo ""

# create an empty commit with a committer date set to 2 days ago minus 1 minute
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$var1 git commit --allow-empty -m 'Create an empty commit'

# display the log; there should only be 1 commit
git log --pretty=fuller
echo ""

# Every 10 seconds for 70 seconds, display the log before 2 days ago without a time specified.
# As soon as the current time passes the time of the commiter_date on the commit, the log will show.
for (( x=1; x<=8; x++ ))
do  
    echo "Current time: $(date)"
    echo "Output of: 'git log --before=$var2':"
    git log --before=$var2
    echo ""
    echo "Output of: 'git log --after=$var2':"
    git log --after=$var2
    echo ""
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Still badly documented. This is not how dates or anything else that has a sequential orderly order works. "Before X" does not include X, as in "nobody expects that".

Comment: The problem isn't so much with "before" as using a non-standard expansion of `2021-07-02` to be the end of the day rather than the beginning (which I think is a far more common interpretation).

Comment: No, the "end of day" interpretation is exactly what programmers do. For everyone else, "2021-07-02" is a date, not a time on that date. Before the 2nd of February does not mean "any time on the 2nd of February or before", it really means "before". The 1st of February is before, 12 o'clock on 2nd of February is comparing apples and oranges, one is a date, the other is a time of day on a date, and if you ask any non-programmer whether "12 o'clock on 2nd of February" is "before 2nd of February" you're either going to get a "no" or a tilted head asking "what are you actually asking right now".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen since I tested late in the day, I wrongly concluded that the times were end of day. IMHO the newly updated answer is even worse news, since every time you run it you could get a different result! Also, please go upvote jthill's answer, since he discovered it before I did.

Comment: @chepner please see my previous comment.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: you're quite correct. But note that "after 2nd of Feb" clearly means Feb 3 and later, not 23:59:59 of Feb 2 for instance. Yet if you ask that same human if "after 2nd Feb" includes *on* 2-Feb, you'll probably get a "yes" answer *provided* you prefix the question with one about exactly what "before 2nd Feb" means. Humans are simply not consistent.

Comment: Found this while troubleshooting my CI scripts. If this were ever to change (unlikely with backwards-compatibility promises), the different range edges would be for "before"/"after" vs. "until"/"since", I suppose - and that could be consistent (e.g. "since/until Feb 2" means including Feb 2, "after/before Feb 2" means excluding that day). And then time zones come into play, your Feb 2 is my Feb 3 for the same seconds-expressed timestamp baked into the Git metadata, because we live in different places... (and yes, there are offset and city and abbr syntaxes Git understands to convey that too).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify a time on your cutoff it uses the current wall clock,so `--before=yesterday` asked at 5pm means before 5pm yesterday. If you want to specify midnight add `T00:00`, `--before=yesterday.T00:00`. I have this as surprising enough to count as a full-fledged wart, like `find`'s behavior with sizes. This is unfortunately used by core commands, so-called "plumbing", and Git has explicitly promised script writers that their behavior and so this date parsing wart won't change.

edit: try this:

```
unset head; for h in {0..23}; do
    head=$( GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=`date -d yesterday\ T$h:00` \
                    git commit-tree ${head+-p $head} -m - @: )
done

git log -1 --pretty=fuller $head
git log -1 --pretty=fuller --before=yesterday $head
```

and you'll see that `before=yesterday` picks the one with the commit timestamp before the current wall clock.